# How to animate a box opening using geometry nodes only?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I've read quite a few questions here about animating a box opening, but is this possible to do using only geometry nodes?

The animation can be a box opening from any side, so I guess even a simple cube to start from wouldn't be a problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very simple example:

[image]

[image]

So that the individual faces of the cube can be processed separately from each other, I first apply the node `Split Edges`. This way I get separate faces.

From these I simply separate the face with index $0$ (in the case of the cube this is the topmost face).

To be able to rotate it comfortably, I turn it into an instance with `Geometry to Instance`. This allows me to achieve a rotation with only one value around a certain point. The node `Rotate Instances` does the rotation here.

I simply take the rotation point from one of the vertices of the face with the node `Bounding Box`.

The rotation itself I bring in via a *Group Input*. This way I can control the opening of the box via keyframe.

[image]

Comment: So is this possible to do with more than 1 flap?

Comment: @TheUnknownContributor You can basically apply the same technique to any number of faces/flaps. Basically, it depends on what result you want to achieve, but that's probably a very individual question/answer.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot for the answer!